# How to create a Web Service that accepts attributes in elements?

Tags: apex, webservices

How do I expose an Apex method as a WebService that accepts the following input:

```
<soap:Body>
   <request>
       <myelement type="something">
        ...
       </myelement>
   </request>
</soap:Body>
```

The problem is that I am able to create the "type" as an element - a child under "myelement" like this:

```
<myelement>
   <type>something</type>
</myelement>
```

But I am not able to make the "type" as an attribute to "myelement".
When we consume webservices in salesforce, the stubs have the following properties to make allow attributes :

> private String[] type_x_att_info = new String[]{'type'};

But when we try to publish a WebService, how do we do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that answer is that you can't currently.

The only way to mark a member of a parameter or return type class is with the `webservice` keyword.

As you found, this results in an element rather than an attribute of the in the generated WSDL complexType.

The most relevant documentation I could find was [Considerations for Using the WebService Keyword](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_web_services_methods_considerations.htm).

> You must use the `webService` keyword with any member variables that you want to expose as part of a Web service. You should not mark these member variables as `static`.

There is no mention of how you could indicate that the member should be an attribute rather than an element.

You could raise this as an [ideaExchange idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaHome) and link to it from this question/answer.